lightweight-charts draw rectangle, risk/reward tradingview
I tried to find a way to draw rectangles with lightweight charts but didnt find anything online. So I was going to write my own plugin for it.
My idea was to plot trades in a similar look to. the risk/reward tool in tradingview
While writing my own plugins I also used the https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-lwc-plugin to get some more information about how to write the plugin.
I first mistakenly tried to create a "Custom series" but after a while realized that it cant be used for custom positions on the x axis. So I then tried to create a "Drawing primitive plugin".
And then I checked the generated code from ```npm create lwc-plugin@latest````
And realized that the generated stuff is almost exactly what I need. It allows to programatically draw rectangles.
So if you want to do it as well, just use the npm create lwc-plugin@latest and select drawing primitive.
 Result looks like on the image


Use npm create lwc-plugin@latest
Then select drawing primitive. the example code that gets generated is the code to draw rectangles. you can use those rectangles to easily draw the Risk/Reward
In my case the usage of the "Rectangle Plugin" looked like this
  // Entry line
        const entryLine = chart.addLineSeries({
          color: "black",
          lineWidth: 1,

          priceLineVisible: false,
        });

        entryLine.setData([
          {
            time: dateToUtcTimestamp(trade.entryTime as unknown as string),
            value: trade.entry,
          },
          {
            time: dateToUtcTimestamp(
              adjustExitTime(trade.entryTime, rMultipleDataForTrade.exitTime)
            ),
            value: trade.entry,
          }, 
        ]);


   const profitArea = new Rectangle(
          { price: trade.entry, time: dateToUtcTimestamp(trade.entryTime) },
          {
            price: rMultipleDataForTrade.targetPrice,
            time: dateToUtcTimestamp(
              adjustExitTime(trade.entryTime, rMultipleDataForTrade.exitTime)
            ),
          },
          {
            fillColor: "rgba(39, 245, 80, 0.43)",
            result: rMultipleDataForTrade.result,
          }
        );

        const stopLossArea = new Rectangle(
          { price: trade.entry, time: dateToUtcTimestamp(trade.entryTime) },
          {
            price: trade.sl,
            time: dateToUtcTimestamp(
              adjustExitTime(trade.entryTime, rMultipleDataForTrade.exitTime)
            ),
          },
          {
            fillColor: "rgba(242, 25, 25, 0.6)",
          }
        );

        // plot original trade take profit
        const originalTakeProfitArea = new Rectangle(
          { price: trade.entry, time: dateToUtcTimestamp(trade.entryTime) },
          {
            price: trade.tp,
            time: dateToUtcTimestamp(
              adjustExitTime(trade.entryTime, trade.exitTime)
            ),
          },
          {
            fillColor: "rgba(170, 224, 167, 0.5)",
          }
        );
        entryLine.attachPrimitive(originalTakeProfitArea);
        entryLine.attachPrimitive(profitArea);
        entryLine.attachPrimitive(stopLossArea);


Hey, is there a reason you're creating a new line series to attach the primitive to? Why not just attach it to the main price series - is there a performance gain doing it this way perhaps?
